# How to use multiple factories in Angular to access uid sent from server

Tags: angularjs

I am creating and sending a UID on the server side to the client side when the user visits a web page. I would like to use that UID as the subfolder to store each project a particular user posts to the server. I'm trying to figure out how best to accomplish this. When I use the code below, I am unable to access the UID in the Projects factory from the UserFactory.

Javascript (Angular):

```
myApp.factory('UserFactory', function UserFactory($http, API_URL, AuthTokenFactory, $q) {

  return $http.get(API_URL + '/api/authenticate').then(function success(response) {
  AuthTokenFactory.setToken(response.data.token);

  return response;
  });
});

myApp.factory('AuthTokenFactory', function AuthTokenFactory($window) {
  var store = $window.localStorage;
  var key = 'auth-token';

  return {
   getToken: getToken,
    setToken: setToken
  };

  function getToken() {
     return store.getItem(key);
 }

  function setToken(token) {
    if (token) {
      store.setItem(key, token);
    } else {
      store.removeItem(key);
    }
  }
});

myApp.factory('Projects', function($http, API_URL, UserFactory, AuthTokenFactory) {

  var uid = UserFactory.response.data.token

  var Projects = {
  };

  Projects.get = function(id) {
  return $http.get(API_URL + '/api/projects/' + uid + id);
  };

  Projects.create = function(userData) {
  return $http.post(API_URL + '/api/projects/' + uid, userData).then(function error(response) {
   var data = response.data;
});
};

  return Projects;

});
```

Node

```
apiRouter.get('/authenticate', function(req, res) {

var uid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
   var r = Math.random()*16|0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8);
   return v.toString(16);
  });

 var token = jwt.sign({
    uid: uid

     }, superSecret, {
         expiresInMinutes: 1440 // expires in 24 hours
            });

            res.json({
                success: true,
                message: 'Enjoy your token!',
                uid: uid,
                token: token
            });
    });
```

Comment: You can use `AuthTokenFactory` to get the token. What your returning from  UserFactory is a promise object and you need a thennable function to access that data inside profilefactory

Comment: it's not really clear from this code how `UserFactory` would even have that token data available. Inside `UserFactory` you call `setToken` on `AuthTokenFactory` - and then what?

Comment: @kaveman Based on your comment and the one above, I must be doing something wrong. For what it's worth, if I do a `console.log(response.data.uid)` within the UserFactory, I get the uid. But I can't access that uid from within the Projects factory.

Comment: @Ken - from inside the `$http.get.then` callback, you would have access to `response.data.uid` (this callback is the handler for the http response). What does `AuthTokenFactory` look like - what does it do with the token and why can't `Projects` use the token from there?

Comment: I think you may have a timing issue. I am not confident that the way you're using it in Projects is guaranteed to have all of your promises fire before it moves on past the uid=xxx assignment. Have you merged the UserFactory call into Projects just to test?

Comment: @kaveman I added the AuthTokenFactory above. I would think that I should be able to access the uid in Project from the token in AuthTokenFactory, but I'm not having any luck with that.

Comment: @tokkov I haven't merged UserFactory into Projects to test. I'll do that. If there is a timing issue, how would you recommend addressing it?

Comment: it looks like UserFactory is `return response;` instead of `return response.data;`

Comment: If it is a timing issue then you would likely be best served with chaining another promise to the (current) UserFactory's $http.get that triggers the Project.create() function. That way you ensure that it doesn't try to write anything until you know that you have the UID in hand. I think it is likely that the way you are returning things out of UserFactory is the root of the issue and you'd probably be better served explicitly storing the UID somewhere separate from the action of creating it. Of course that moves the problem to when/where to get a new one.